# Append child's first row to parent relation in PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **users** and **transactions** table

```
users
____________
id | name

transactions
____________
id | user_id | amount
```

so users have many transactions

I want to calculate sum of users first transactions amount

for example we have two users Alice and Alison
Alica have two transactions first transaction amount is 10 second transaction amount is 9
Alison have two transactions first transaction amount is 20 second transaction amount is 80

so I want data 10+20=30 output should be 30 :)

I tried this:

```
SELECT *, (select amount from transactions where users.id = transactopns.user_id order by id asc limit 1) as first_amount FROM users
```

but I have no idea how can I make sum of this ;)

```
SELECT *, (select amount from transactions where users.id = transactopns.user_id order by id asc limit 1) as first_amount FROM users
```

Comment: So a smallest order_id for that user is their first transaction? Look into `select sum(amount) from (select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by order_id asc) as rn from your_table) where rn = 1`

Comment: @Isolated, if you have a solution, please post it as an answer instead of a comment, or else the question will remain in the "unanswered" category forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() to get their first transaction. Something like this should work, but not sure what you want to return in your results. Basically, look into row_number() then wrap your query to get the SUM.

```
select sum(amount) 
  from (
    select u.id, u.name, t.id, t.amount, 
      row_number() over (partition by t.user_id order by t.id asc) as rn
    from users u 
    join transactions t
      on u.id = t.user_id
      )z 
where rn = 1
```